# Can i exclude DE with different Subscriber Key?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data, sql

I have 2 data extensions:

1 - DataExtension A (ID column is primary key and marked as Subscriber Key)

2 - DataExtension B (Email column is primary key and marked as Subscriber Key)

Now, when i send email to DataExtension A, can I use DataExtension B as exclusion?

For exclusion, do I need same Subscriber Key in both data extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can, but you might run into an issue when you look at your send relationship. The system must map the "SubscriberKeys" in the AllSubscriber list. This have to be the same values or the system will recognise them as Two different subscribers rendering your Exclusion Invalid.

**TLDR** When you create your DE make sure the subscriberkey field is mapped to what the value is in the AllSubscriberList

Comment: I tried testing it and yes system treats same record as two different record. I guess I cannot exclude.